# Can I add additional information to a php error log - *only* when it errors?

Tags: php, logging, error-handling

My php setup currently records errors in the standard php_errorlog file. These errors tell me things like the type of error and the line it occurred on (standard stuff).

I'd like to add more information to this log, but **only** when an error occurs.

For example, I'd like to create a variable `$error_details` at the top of my script, into which I'd put things like the id of the user logged in at the time, and the `php://input` details.

I know I can write `error_log($error_details)`, but this would record *every* time my script runs. I want it to record *only* when there is an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the error_get_last function.

```
if (error_get_last()) {
    //Error occurred
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that **control error logs** with libraries or self coding with tomuch works.

[Monolog - Logging for PHP](https://seldaek.github.io/monolog/)

Library and nice examples for basic types on [Loggy](https://www.loggly.com/)

**PHP Error Log Types**

PHP provides a variety of error log types for identifying the severity of errors encountered when your application runs.

The error levels indicate if the engine couldn’t parse and compile your PHP statements, or couldn’t access or use a resource needed by your application, all the way down to letting you know if you have a possible typo in a variable name.

Although the error levels are integer values, there are predefined constants for each one.

Using the constants will make your code easier to read and understand and keep it forward-compatible when new error levels are introduced.

Common error levels encountered include:

Check for [Predefined Constants](https://www.php.net/errorfunc.constants)

And here nice Tutorials : [Ultimate Guide to Logging](https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/php-logging-basics/)

**Another Way is the base exception**

PHP has a base Exception class that is available by default in the language. 
The base Exception class is extensible if required.

**Example**: (assumes directive `log_errors = 1`).

```
try{

if(true){

throw new Exception("Something failed", 900);

}

} catch (Exception $e) {

$datetime = new DateTime();

$datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

$logEntry = $datetime->format('Y/m/d H:i:s') . ‘ ‘ . $e;



// log to default error_log destination

error_log($logEntry);

//Email or notice someone
//OR use fopen(); function and write in to error_log file

}
```

The example above would produce the following error log entry:

```
2020/01/05 15:02:24/Something failed/900//var/www/html/index.php/4
```